# Как развиваться дальше в REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Доброго времени суток )Несколько месяцев изучал  react и вот написал небольшой интернет магазин с redux, react-router ,contentful API :

https://quintis1212.github.io/react-shop-max/build/#/

Что изучать дальше по направлению frontend react? Какие практические задачи можно сделать для повышения моего уровня в react? Можно ли при моем уровне знаний найти работу?

Comment: я отсюда задачи беру https://www.frontendmentor.io/

Comment: @grime мне кажется там очень легкие задачи

Comment: Работу можно начинать искать. А пока попутно можете удариться в верстку и стили\анимации.

Comment: @ Stepan Kasyanenko можете скинуть ссылку на материал , примеры хорошей верстки , что б конкретно знать к чему идти ?)

Comment: для разминки добавь в проект SASS, как сказали ниже сейчас актуальны хуки, кроме редакса можно изучить mobx;

Answer (score 2):

Перепишите проект используя Redux-Saga. Изучите react/redux hooks. Попробуйте сконфигурировать webpack config с нуля. Разберитесь с material-ui и css-in-js. Освойте unit тестирование с использованием jest/enzyme.

Comment: Здраствуйте , можете скинуть хороший ютуб канал по  unit тестированию . Можете навести практический пример  react/redux hooks для проекта

Answer (score 1):

**Советую изучать HTML, CSS и при этом для сложных задач применять React.(Больше шансов найти работу в сфере web).Если GameDev на Реакте то советую DirectX полностью изучить для понимания строения программы на графическом движке.**